# I need a datasheet for an 8-pin IC marked 206 5128A3GX

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet

[image]

I want to know what this IC is and its manufacturer name.  It will be useful if you also let me know how you found the datsheet.

Comment: Did you try the Google image search? Many have had success with that.

Comment: To invite useful answers here, disclose the purpose of the board. (looks protection measures from water/humidity?)

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Giantec GT25C128A](https://en.giantec-semi.com/uploads/20220929/0d378a54f0ce39b6d509720193c8a08f.pdf) EEPROM.
[image]

The markings don't match exactly, but are very close. <strike>I suspect it's the [automotive grade version](https://en.giantec-semi.com/EEPROM/Automotive-grade-EEPROM), but I can't confirm since there is no part number shown on the website.</strike>
Edit: It looks like the automotive version has a "B" instead of "A". The datasheet says there are custom package option available on request:

[image]

So I suspect it's in a custom package with the designator "3GX".

Comment: Thank you bro ..you are doing a great work..! and again how did you find this datasheet 

Comment: @GaneshThiva This one was tricky. After a search for the markings code turned up nothing. I looked up IC logo databases to search for the manufacturer, but couldn't find any match. Since it didn't seem to be one of the bigger western brands, I looked on https://www.lcsc.com/supplier for manufacturers with a name that could be abbreviated as GT or CT. After looking at quite a few, I finally found Giantec with a matching logo. Then I searched their homepage for a part that matches the markings code.

Comment: What seems strange to me is that this relies on it being a custom package code, but SOIC is one of the standard packages with a standard code. I wonder if it's just a different pinout or something....